# Editing user in django views error: The view feedback.views.users_edit didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django, django-views, python-3.8

I have CRUD operations for users. Everything is working well, except my function for edit users. It saves the changes, but when I tried to check if I can change the username to an existing username it gives me:

> ValueError: The view feedback.views.users_edit didn't return an
> HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

**views.py**

```
def users_edit(request, id=0):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if id == 0:
            form = UserForm()
        else:
            users =  CustomUser.objects.get(pk=id)
            form = UserForm(instance=users)
        return render(request, 'useredit.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        if id == 0:
            form = UserForm(request.POST)
        else:
            users =  CustomUser.objects.get(pk=id)
            form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=users)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('feedback:users')
```

**userdelete.html**

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}


{% block content %}

<p>Are you sure to delete this {{user.email}} ?</p>
    <form action="{% url 'feedback:userdelete' user.id %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <a href="{% url 'feedback:users' %}">Cancel</a>
        <input type="submit" name="Confirm">
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

I'm using django2.2

Comment: if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('feedback:users')
What happen if the form is not valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a line out of your if blocks to return a response or render type response in case none of your conditions are checked... for example add

```
return HttpResponse('Some message here')
```

as a last line in your view just to make sure in any case your view will return a response object.

PS edit the whole code if someone found it useful:

```
def users_edit(request, id=0):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if id == 0:
            form = UserForm()
        else:
            users =  CustomUser.objects.get(pk=id)
            form = UserForm(instance=users)
        return render(request, 'useredit.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        if id == 0:
            form = UserForm(request.POST)
        else:
            users =  CustomUser.objects.get(pk=id)
            form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=users)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('feedback:users')
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'useredit.html', context)
```

Comment: Understood, but how to render the current form too, with this message?

Comment: Add something like `context = {'form': form}` and `return render(request, 'your_template.html', context=context)` in your else condition after the line `return redirect('feedback:users')` and outside of it's if condition block.

Answer (score 0):

If request.method is not 'POST' and the form is invalid, you reach the end of the view function without any *return* statement. By default, every function returns *None* which is not a HttpResponse object.

You must alway return responses from your views.